# In rails 3, how do I use page.call to call a function and pass it multiple parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using page.call to call a function in my rails application that is using jquery-ujs. Right now I have it working fine with one parameter being passed:

```
page.call "functionName", "div_name"
```

to call

```
functionName(div_name)
{
}
```

but I'd like to pass two parameters to this function:

```
functionName(div_name, other_variable)
{
}
```

How can I do this using page.call?

Thanks so much.

Comment: yes! updated to reflect that.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `page.call`? This would probably be best implemented with javascript views and ajax requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried simply adding another argument to the call? It looks like [`page.call()`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/JavaScriptGenerator/GeneratorMethods.html#method-i-call) uses varargs for the arguments.

You should simply be able to do

```
page.call 'functionName', 'arg1', 'arg2'
```